# Paginate API Laravel

Tags: oracle, api, laravel, pagination

I am building an API in Laravel which does the following to Oracle database:

select * from table_a;

Here is the API code:

```
$response = [];
try {
    $response['status']     = 200;
    $response['message']    = 'ok';
    $response['parameters'] = [];
    $obj                    = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_a");
    if (!empty($obj) && count($obj)) {
        $response['result'] = $obj;
    }
    else {
        $response['result'] = 'Requested data not found';
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $response['status']     = 400;
    $response['message']    = 'ok';
    $response['parameters'] = [];
    $response['result']     = 'Sorry! bad request';
}

return response()->json($response);
```

table_a has more than 30 million records. I need to paginate API results. I cannot count the table records each time as it takes a few minutes for the count query to execute. How can I get it efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paginate your results with [**`->paginate('n')`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination). The `paginate` method provided by Laravel automatically takes care of setting the proper limit and offset based on the current page being viewed by the user. By default, the current page is detected by the value of the `?page` query string argument on the HTTP request.

In this case, let's specify that we would like to display `15` items per page:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show all of the users for the application.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);

        return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use Oracle table(s), so it would be using a stored procedure at Oracle level. It's not a normal table.